# Reduce multiplexers number after VHDL synthesis

Tags: vhdl, synthesis

I'm writing a design in VHDL and after synthesis I observed that the number of multiplexers (dedicated) used is high. My code has a lot of if-else staments, so it seems logical.

But I wanna know if it is possible to implement if-else (or similar staments) in another way to reduce the number of multiplixers resources used.

Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes you can restructure if-else statements as case statements. And sometimes case statements can be implemented as lookup tables. Or, sometimes you can implement the lookup table directly, as a constant array, which you index using whatever quantity you tested in the if-statement. Whether these apply to your case depends on context you haven't told us.

Comment: When you say multiplexers, do you mean dedicated mux resource, or just the various size multiplexers implemented using LUTs? Are you running out of a particular resource?

Comment: @scary_jeff dedicated resources

Comment: The implication is that you have a lot of wide multiplexers. That being the case, I don't see what you could do to reduce mux usage; you might have to re-think parts of your design that are creating lots of multiplexers, or move to a bigger part.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use simple logic elements like `and` or `or`. For example:

```
if (a and b) = '1' then
   out_0 <= '1';
else
   out_0 <= '0';
end if;

if (c or d) = '1' then
   out_1 <= '1';
else
   out_1 <= '0';
end if;
```

This is construction can be replaced with following:

```
out_0 <= a and b;
out_1 <= c or d;
```

And so on...